# Eclipse Content Assist in Visual Studio style

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

In Visual Studio the proposals the content assist gives for variable names, members and functions will search through the entire string that was typed.

For example, when you would type "instance", and somewhere you have a member declared as "m_DecalInstance", then this member would still show in the proposals of auto complete.

However, in Eclipse only the start of the name of the member is accounted for. So m_DecalInstance would only show up if you would start with typing "m_Dec" instead of "instanc", for example.

Is there any way to enable such a feature for Eclipse as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Eclipse Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders) project includes [subwords completion](http://eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#completion-engines) which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!